# pwm input to rpi from LIDAR sensor

Tags: pwm

I want to use pwm signal as input which is the output of LIDAR sensor that i want to interface with R-Pi. So please help me I am new to Rpi and pwm as input. How can i read the pwm signal in Rpi .Please if anyone have some reference code post it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: PWM is defined by two characteristics - frequency and dutycycle.  What does the LIDAR PWM look like in frequency and dutycycle?

Comment: You just have to track pin changes of a digital input. From the duration of two changes from 1->0 you get the frequency. The duration from 1->0 to 0->1 divided by the duration from 1->0 to the next 1->0 is your duty cycle. So there is not much code, just listen to the input and keep track of the times.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Lidar sensor output in the form of range which is like 0 to 1000 and one conversion factor is there which i have to convert that in PWM pulse that i want to read.